# Create HTML page to run functions of a Python script

Tags: html, python-3.x

I have developed a Python script to execute certain functions depending on the value selected in an output. I have decided to take it one step further and integrate this via HTML page.

I would like to implement a series of checkboxes on the HTML page and allocate each checkbox to a certain Python function, and one checkbox to run all of the functions. These functions should only run when an "Apply Changes" button has been clicked. I would also like to pass an IP address, username, and password to the Python script, which are stored in variables and used throughout the script.

So far, my HTML page has the below output. My Python Functions are `DeleteVSs()`, `ResetCheckParams()`, `DeleteTemplates()`, `DeleteContentRules()`, `GEOPreferences()`, and `DeleteSSO()`. So far, the page renders with the checkboxes displayed, but I need a way to map the checkboxes to the actual Python functions. I'm new to HTML, so how to achieve this task?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Admin</legend>
    <p>
          <label>LoadMaster IP</label>
          <input type = "LoadMaster IP"
                  id = "Loadmaster IP"
                  value = "10.1.105.8" />
    <p>
          <label>Username</label>
          <input type = "Username"
                 id = "Username"
                 value = "bal" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>Password</label>
          <input type = "Password"
                  id = "Password"
                  value = "" />
        </p>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend>What options would you like to delete?</legend>

    <script src="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LMConfig\Delete\DefaultLMConfig.py"></script>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="All" value="All">
        <label for="All">All</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="VSs" name="VSs" value="VSs">
        <label for="VSs">VSs</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Check Parameters" name="Check Parameters" value="Check Parameters">
        <label for="Check Parameters">Check Parameters</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Templates" name="Templates" value="Templates">
        <label for="Templates">Templates</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Content Rules" name="Content Rules" value="ContentRules">
        <label for="Content Rules">Content Rules</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="GEO" name="GEO" value="GEO">
        <label for="GEO">GEO</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="ESP" name="ESP" value="ESP">
        <label for="ESP">ESP</label>
    </div>
    <br></br>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Delete Selected Options</button>
    </div>
</fieldset>

</body>
</html>
```